# React useEffect Typescript problem: multiple return types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a get function that fetches data, either products or user data, depending on the URL:

```js
export type TGet = (path: string) => Promise<IProduct[]> | Promise<IUser>

export const get: TGet = (path: string) => {
    return fetch("https://" + window.location.hostname + ":4001/" + path, {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: "include",
        mode: "cors",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }).then(r => {
        return r.json();
    });
};
```

When the product component loads, I use useEffect to fetch the product data:

```js
const Product = ({ match }: RouteComponentProps<TParams>) => {
    const [product, setProduct] = useState<IProduct[]>([]);
    const content = () => {
        if (product.length === 0) {
            return <div>loading data...</div>;
        }
        return <div>{JSON.stringify(product)}</div>;
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        get(`api/fixture/products/${match.params.id}`).then((productData) => {
            setProduct(productData);
        });
    }, [match.params.id]);

    return content();
};
```

The problem here is the setProduct line:

> Argument of type 'IProduct[] | IUser' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'SetStateAction<IProduct[]>'.   Type 'IUser' is not assignable
> to type 'SetStateAction<IProduct[]>'.
> Type 'IUser' is not assignable to type '(prevState: IProduct[]) => IProduct[]'.
> Type 'IUser' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: IProduct[]): IProduct[]'.  TS2345

I mean I know that setProduct cannot be updated with with Userdata, but since I say in the function type TGet that the return value can be a productList OR userdata, I'd assume TS doesn't try to force userdata into the match here.
What's the proper way to tell Typescript: yes the function CAN return userdata, but in the instance of this useState invokation IT FOR SURE IS a productList?

Comment: try to add to your state useState<IProduct [] | IUser>([])

Comment: TypeScript does not know the return type of the Ajax call. You can typecast the response object to the expected type using the 'as' operator e.g. productData as IProduct[];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean by your question, that your state can be IUser [] or IProduct[].
Then you use `useState<IProduct[] | IUser[]>([])`.

If you have some data that you know 100% sure, they are for example IUser[], you can use in code this `return data as IUser[]` for IProduct also `data as IProduct[]`

Hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments I was able to solve this with

```js
setProduct(productData as IProduct[]);
```

Comment: seems like i came late :D nice, glad you solved your issue :)